# Can you guys help me debunk this anti-gay statement?

Tags: sexuality

According to Dr Bob Cabaj, the former president of the Gay and Lesbian Medical Association, “bug chasers” (those who actively seek to contract HIV/AIDS) account for 10,000 of the 40,000 new cases of HIV in the United States every year. " I found the article tries was referring to: http://www.rollingstone.com/culture/features/in-search-of-death-20030206 
The man quoted later said he was misquoted, but someone else said this in response to me: "But if Freeman and the RS fact-checker really completely FABRICATED the entire section attributed to Dr Cabaj , where is the lawsuit?
It seems that Cabaj regretted the confession after the Rolling Stone piece got huge, and later lied and said he never quoted that because it opened the "LGBT community" to scrutiny he did not foresee. With the incredible amount of money, lobbies and organizations fags have to cover up their behavior, they would've sued and forced Rolling Stone to retract the story by now, but they stuck to their story with no counter from the fags saying it's exagerrating" 
How do I respond to this?

Comment: I'm not clear exactly which claim you are challenging.  The original figure about 10,000 out of 40,000 cases?  The claim that Cabaj said this?  The claim that he lied when he said he was misquoted?  The claim that, if he did lie, it was for specific purposes?  It should also be noted that the article in question is more than 12 years old, so shouldn't necessarily be expected to reflect the current situation in any case.

Comment: Research conclusion is already present per Christian Grov and Jeffrey T. Parsons in 2006 that "bug chasing and gift giving might occur among a select few individuals. There was substantial variation in intentions to spread HIV (with some not intent on spreading HIV) among those who indicated they were gift givers or bug chasers." Limitations of this study were 'the data in this study are based on uncorroborated self-reports' and 'relatively small sample size, particularly with
regard to the behaviors pertaining to gift giving."

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: As far as I understand it, this question is about whether a single article misquoted an interviewee or whether the interviewee was misunderstood, quoted inaccurately etc. Without some form of official inquiry, there are no facts and only hearsay.