# Were 25% of newly-infected HIV-positive gay men actively seeking infection in 2003?

Tags: sexuality, public-health, hiv-aids

[Rense](http://www.rense.com/general33/dswdu.htm) quotes a 2003 Drudge Report article, that previewed an apparent Rolling Stone magazine article titled "Bug Chasers: The Men Who Secretly Long To Be HIV+."

> The men who want the virus are called 'bug chasers' [...]
>
> "At least twenty-five percent of all newly infected gay men fall into [bug-chasing] category, according to one claim in the "special report"."

Was the claim in the Rolling Stone magazine true?

Comment: What Rense said Drudge said Rolling Stone was going to say said is very different to what you said. It doesn't say 25% of gay men seek infection, it says IN 2003 (a long time ago in HIV terms) that OF THE GAY MEN WHO HAD RECENTLY BEEN INFECTED, 25% of them had sought the virus.

Comment: Related, though this question is currently worded much better: [Can you guys help me debunk this anti-gay statement?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/30145/21543)

Comment: Rense..... quoting Drudge.....

Answer (score 54):

The number originates from a [Rolling Stone article titled Bug Chasers](https://web.archive.org/web/20080304003441/http:/www.rollingstone.com/news/story/5939950/bug_chasers) by Gregory Freeman:

> Cabaj estimates that at least twenty-five percent of all newly infected gay men fall into that category.

[Cabaj disputes](http://www.newsweek.com/rolling-stones-hiv-story-wildly-exaggerated-135057) having said this:

> That's totally false. I never said that. And when the fact checker called me and asked me if I said that, I said no. I said no. This is unbelievable.

Apart from Cabaj, the Rolling Stone also attributed claims to Marshall Forstein, who also disputes the quotes (same source as before):

> That is entirely a fabrication

[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2003/jan/26/pressandpublishing.aids) spoke to a number of physicians who call the claims in the article a fabrication.

[BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/health/4895012.stm) investigated the claim and concludes that bug chasing is a fantasy that exists online, but that is not executed in real life.

[Parsons and Grov](http://guilfordjournals.com/doi/abs/10.1521/aeap.2006.18.6.490) studies the issue and conclude:

> These data suggest bug chasing and gift giving do exist; however a sizable portion of both bug chasers and gift givers were not intent on spreading HIV.

Comment: Just as a curiosity, this phenomenon (people seeking to get infected) happened in Cuba during the economical crisis of the 90-ties, I am not sure how well it has been documented because of the "political restrictions" in the country, but there is at least a movie that dared to touch the topic: [Boleto al paraíso (Ticket to paradise)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1787664/). No correlation with gays that I am aware of though.